# Soap client not working on live server

Tags: php, json, web-services, soap-client

I am getting data from .asmx method using soap client. It is working fine on localhost, but not working on live server. This is my code.

```
//turn off WSDP caching if not in a production environment
$ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","1");
xdebug_disable();
try {
    //instantiate the SOAP client
    $client = new SoapClient("http://ip_address/appName/common/TaskTrackingService.asmx?wsdl");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit("Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ip_address/appName/common/TaskTrackingService.asmx?wsdl'");
}

//checking if object is created
if ($client) {
    //updating user in timings 
    //getting data from GetAllEmployeeIntimesByDay method from timesheet 
    $params->month = date('m');
    $params->year = date('Y');
    $params->day = date('d',strtotime('yesterday'));
    $result = $client->GetAllEmployeeIntimesByDay($params)->GetAllEmployeeIntimesByDayResult;
}
```

Comment: Did you get some errors ?

Comment: No.It is not showing any error. But when I am using soapServer() instead of soapClient(), it is showing WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ip_address/app_name/common/TaskTrackingService.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://ip_address/app_name/common/TaskTrackingService.asmx?wsdl"

Comment: Did you check that you can reach the server which is hosting the wsdl from your production server? You might have a firewall issue.

Comment: Is openssl extension of php required for making SOAP calls ?